# I get an error message whenever I try to run the cypress run --record --key xxxx in VScode terminal

Tags: javascript, automation, integration, cypress

I get an error message whenever I try to run the cypress run --record --key xxxx in VScode terminal.
this is the error:
cypress : The term 'cypress' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image: I get an error message whenever I try to run the cypress run --record --key xxxx in VScode terminal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the npx prefix, try again with this:

```
npx cypress run --record --key <key goes here>
```

Comment: Woohoo.  @kidby I am now connected.